# Girsanov Theorem: Equivalent condition for density

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am studying on Girsanov's theorem. Moreover my lecturer states, following:

$$Z>0\text{ is a continuous local martingale }\Leftrightarrow \exists! \text{ N continuous local martingale }:Z=e^{(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])}$$

Is this still true, when $N$ is only a martingale?

$$Z>0\text{ is a continuous martingale }\Leftrightarrow \exists! \text{ N continuous martingale }:Z=e^{(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])}$$

If yes, is it possible to rewrite the condition "If the Doléans-Dade exponential is a continuous martingale" into "If $N$ is a continuous martingale" ? (I am especially interested in $"\Leftarrow"$)

Proof for the statement: Using Ito's lemma we find both directions:

$"\Leftarrow"$

$$
\begin{align}
Z&=\exp(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])\\
&=\exp(N_0)+\exp(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])\cdot (N-\frac{1}{2}[N])+\frac{1}{2}\exp(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])\cdot[N]\\
&=\exp(N_0)+\exp(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])\cdot N
\end{align}
$$

$"\Rightarrow"$

$$
\begin{align}
\log Z=\log Z_0+Z^{-1}\cdot Z-\frac{1}{2}Z^{-2}\cdot[Z]=(\log Z_0+Z^{-1}\cdot Z)-\frac{1}{2}[\log Z_0+Z^{-1}\cdot Z]
\end{align}
$$

is a semi-martingale with unique decomposition, therefore
$Z=e^{(N-\frac{1}{2}[N])}$
with $N:=\log Z_0+Z^{-1}\cdot Z$

**Looking at the proof, my question seems to narrow down to the following: When is a stochastic integral with respect to a continuous martingale a continuous martingale again?**

Comment: When you have that the integrand is square integrable with respect to the product measure $d(P\otimes \langle M\rangle)$

Comment: Thank you. I actually found another condition for my situation. If $N=H\cdot W$ with a Wiener Process $W$, $Z$ is a martingale if the Novikov condition is fulfilled.

Comment: So I can replace the condition to: "If $N=H\cdot W$ with a Wiener Process $W$, that suffices the Novikov property."